# Integration Testing with .NET Core and NUnit

Tags: testing, asp.net-core, nunit, integration-testing, .net-core

I have a controller that is taking a JWT Claim, and if the claim is correct, then I am returing a Json string of categories as follows :-

```
[Authorize(Policy = "OnlyValidUsers")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class CategoriesController : Controller
{
    private readonly IGenericService<Category> _categoriesService;

    public CategoriesController(IGenericService<Category> categoriesService)
    {
        _categoriesService = categoriesService;
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "GenericUser")]
    [HttpGet("/api/Categories/Get", Name = "GetCategories")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Get()
    {
        var categories = await _categoriesService.GetAll();
        return Json(categories);
    }
}
```

This happens after the user logins in to my system, and gets a bearer token.

I am trying to test that in an integration test as follows:-

```
[TestFixture]
public class CategoriesControllerIntegrationTests
{
    private HttpClient _client;
    private Category _testCategory;
    private string _request;

    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var basePath = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;
        var projectPath = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(basePath, "../../../../SportsStore.Tests"));

        var server = new TestServer(Utils.GetHostBuilder(new string[] { })
            .UseContentRoot(projectPath)
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .UseStartup<Startup>());

        _client = server.CreateClient();
        _testCategory = new Category
        {
            Name = Enums.GetEnumDescription(Enums.CategoryTestData.Name)
        };
        _request = Enums.GetEnumDescription(Enums.Requests.Categories);
    }

    [Test]
    public async Task Get_ReturnsAListOfCategories_CategoriesController()
    {
        var response = await _client.GetAsync(_request + "Get");
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        Assert.IsTrue(true);
    }
```

The Utils class is as follows:-

```
public class Utils
{
    public static IWebHostBuilder GetHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                   .AddCommandLine(args)
                   .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
                   .Build();

        return new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseConfiguration(config)
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseStartup<Startup>();
    }
}
```

When I run the test, I am getting a 401 (Unauthorized) which is expected.  How can I make this test pass?  How can I pass the claim in the test to verify that its working?

Also, if I remove the [Authorize] filters, I am still getting a 401 (Unauthorized) which I think should not happen.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Did you remove both the `Authrize` filters because i see 2 of them (and did you specify even more as global filters)? Either make sure you pass the Authorize Attributes with the tests by providing the right cookie state (login in first for example) or make an override in the policies (but that might leave you vulnerable later).

Comment: I did remove them previously just to check if those were the cause, however  when I did remove them, I still got a 401, that is why I am suspecting that i have something wrong in the Setup.cs or the TestServer

Comment: confirmed that the problem is this             services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

Comment: I need to find a way to pass the policy with my test, no idea how to do that so far though

Comment: I'd advice to either use a different Startup.cs for testing and do different AddMvc. Or make your unit test first login by resolving the SignInManager etc. Dont change your default startup.cs with if else, this could only lead to a security risks

Comment: I was thinking of doing a seperate Startup.cs, however I still have to test the Policies, for example "GenericUser" and "Administrator", so I still need a way to pass these policies to the API

Comment: Does this mean that in integration testing you do not mock your external dependencies instead you use them directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Authorization` header for each request of http client:

```
_client = server.CreateClient();
_client .DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "VALID JWT goes here");
```

This way you will not need separate configurations for tests and real environment.